# Placing two tables on Data Report in VB6? Using Msaccess

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb6

How can I place these two tables on Data Report in VB6..? Using Msaccess
[image]

[image]

See the name belongs to table2 contain two fields that repeats when i submit
print button. Please help me to solve this.

My query is

```
SELECT* FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON
Table1.Billno=Table2.Billno Where (Table1.Billno=? AND Table2.Billno=?)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 SELECT a.Slno, a.Name1, b.Name2
 FROM table1 a
 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 b ON b.SLno = a.Slno
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7ccd4/1

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want them back as two separate results, in which case you should perform two queries.

`SELECT * FROM Table1`
`SELECT * FROM Table2`

If you need them back as one result set then you could `UNION ALL` them together.

```
SELECT [S1 No], BillNo, Name1 AS Name FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT [S1 No], BillNo, Name2 AS Name FROM Table2
```

But I don't think that is a good suggestion.